# Need help identifying this IC

Tags: hardware

Does anybody know which IC this is? I cannot find anything for "2746 QA7A" or any combination of it. Neither do I recognise the manufacturer.
The IC is actually very small, so I cannot take a better photo of it.

What I already found out:
The IC is connected to six touch keys, the upper five pins and the first pin on the lower left are connected to the touch pads. Then there are 3 data lines connected to an ST32. May be I2C.

Thanks for any hint!

[image: unknown IC]

Comment: **please do not cripple your question by removing the photo after getting it answered!** I rolled back the crippling edit. If there is a real concern about private data, sure you can flag it and we can redact old revisions. But the photo contains no EXIF metadata and without the photo the question becomes nearly meaningless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an AT42QT2120 QTouch sensor IC from Atmel.

Comment: Can you describe how you found it out?